# Error during docker exec

Tags: linux, docker

There are many container in my docker. When I start one of container exec, I got error like this:

```
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:75: starting setns process caused \\\"fork/exec /proc/self/exe: no such file or directory\\\"\"\n"
```

Neithor sh or bash did I get this error, but the start of the other container exec works well.

Comment: Can you please share necessary steps to reproduce. Probably the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @vivekyad4v I have no Dokerfile, and this container is copied from another container. Before today it did work well. Today, I can connect this container by ssh, but I can't exec it. What if you want more other information, just tell me.

Comment: how you are executing command inside docker

Comment: try with
docker exec -it name ash
docker exec -it name bash
ash or bash can be valid

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25381 is similar but inconclusive; the two things comments there suggest as possible causes are the Docker filesystem (in the old loopback devicemapper mode) being full and manually unmounting directories in `/var/lib/docker`.